# Scrapy script not scrapping items

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Im not sure why my script isnt scrapping any items, is the same script that im using for another website, maybe the classes im using are wrong.

`

```
import scrapy
import os
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")

class stiendaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stienda'
    start_urls = ['https://stienda.uy/tv']

    def parse(self, response):
        for products in response.css('.grp778'):
            price = products.css('.precioSantander::text').get()
            name = products.css('#catalogoProductos .tit::text').get()
            if price and name:
                yield {'name': name.strip(),
                       'price': price.strip()}

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\cabre\\Desktop\\scraping\\stienda\\data\\raw')
process = CrawlerProcess(
#    settings={"FEEDS": {"items.csv": {"format": "csv"}}}
     settings={"FEEDS": {f"stienda_{date}.csv": {"format": "csv"}}}
)
process.crawl(stiendaSpider)
process.start()
```

`

I tried several but I dont usnderstand why is not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the name field, but the price attribute is rendered empty and filled in later from an ajax call.  That is why it's not being extracted.

```
import scrapy
import os
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")

class stiendaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stienda'
    start_urls = ['https://stienda.uy/tv']

    def parse(self, response):
        for products in response.xpath('//div[@data-disp="1"]'):
            name = products.css('.tit::text').get()
            if name:
                yield {'name': name.strip()}
```

You can see it if you look at the page source... all of the elements with the class `'precioSantander'`  are empty.

[image]

Comment: You think there is no way to do it because of that?

Comment: @Bruno123  there is no way to get it with scrapy alone.  If you want to try using playwright, splash, or selenium or some other javascript rendering service you could.

Comment: That’s doable? Do you have any tutorial I can read to extract just that price? Thank you!

Comment: @Bruno123  My suggestion would be to open a new question with all of the details you just learned and specify the new problem you are facing and someone who is better versed in javascript rendering with scrapy will be able to answer your question.  Use a title like "extracing element rendered from ajax with scrapy" or something like that...